# JS infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do i set an infinite loop on the JS below? At the bottom it has a timer to run at 50 seconds i need it to run every 50 seconds. My JS knowledge is 0%. I have no idea whats even going on below, some of it was explained to me though, so very small but vague understanding.

```
//an array for later use at line 30 and line 35.
var classnames = ["one","two","three","four","five","six"];

//Used css3 selector for class (".classname") 
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".ani");

setTimeout(function() {
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
var element = elements[i];

//e.g elements[0] removes class "one", elements[1] removes "two"
element.classList.remove(classnames[i]);

element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;

//e.g elements[0] adds class "one", elements[1] adds "two"
element.classList.add(classnames[i]);
}
}, (50*1000));
```

Comment: take a look into `setInterval()` http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: Why would you need to remove the same class every 50 seconds? Sounds more like a flaw in logic?

Comment: Presumably you're also trying to re-render some elements, `element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;` doesn't work for that, since [`offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth) is read-only.

Comment: _"My JS knowledge is 0%. I have no idea whats even going on below, some of it was explained to me though, so very small but vague understanding."_ ~ StackOverflow is geared towards professional and enthusiast programmers, so typically we cannot provide answers detailed enough for somebody without the prerequisite background knowledge.  Look at @adeneo's comment... do you know why you need to do this?  Perhaps there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish with the elements you're working with, but I'll leave that alone as it's outside the direct scope of your question.

Looking just at the question of how to run every 50 seconds, many are going to recommend `setinterval`. I, however, would recommend you stick with `setTimeout` and adjust your code to run recursively (calling the function again, from within itself, in a setTimeout).

I offer this alternative because `setInterval` will continue to queue up calls to your code even if something in your code takes a while and has not yet finished. This can lead to race conditions, bogged down performance, etc. By using `setTimeout` we ensure that a run has completed before a new one is scheduled.

Here is your code modified to do what I suggest:

```
var classnames = ["one","two","three","four","five","six"],
    elements = document.querySelectorAll(".ani"),
    // put the logic into a function which we can call
    cycler = function () {
        var i,
            c = elements.length,
            element;

        for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            // your original element manipulation code, odd as it may be
            element = elements[i];

            element.classList.remove(classnames[i]);
            element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;

            element.classList.add(classnames[i]);
        }

        // queue up another run
        cycle_timer = setTimeout(cycler, 50*1000);
    },
    //somewhere to store the return of setTimeout so we can stop it if we want
    cycle_timer = null;

// start it up!
cycler();

// if you want to stop it:
clearTimeout(cycle_timer);
```

Comment: This is a good point, especially when using remarkably smaller interval, I can't imagine any JS code taking 50 secs or more...

Comment: @Teemu yes, the 50 second timer does make the problem less likely. I have made it practice, however, to never use `setInterval` so that I don't have to consider whether and issue will arise or worry about someone deciding the interval should be shorter in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
  // do your stuff here
}, 50*1000);
```